# Crash [UIAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uialertview

I just got notified that one of my users had a crash caused by the call [UIAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:].

Now only **one user** has **ever** had this crash in 6 months of production usage, so it has to be a very rare case.

The thing is *I'm not happy leaving any open issues regardless of how rare*.

Knowing that I only have one UIAlertView in my entire app, it was easy to track down what bit of code would be the likely suspect. However looking at it, I'm semi-baffled by **why** it would cause a crash. I'm not setting a delegate, and I'm only using the standard cancel button. The app is using ARC so it should be autoreleased since I'm not grabbing a pointer.

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Notice"
                      message:@"This App Requires Location Services and Region Monitoring to Be Enabled"
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

Is my crash reporting accusing the wrong chunk of code, or am I overlooking something?

Crash Log:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xb1e2c0eb
0com.apple.main-thread Crashed
Latest crash : 5/03/2013 at 11:10:19 UTC-0700
0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 15
1    UIKit   -[UIAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:] + 256
2    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 72
3    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
4    UIKit   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
5    UIKit   -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 502
6    UIKit   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 488
7    UIKit   -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
8    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 380
9    UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
10   GraphicsServices    _PurpleEventCallback + 590
11   GraphicsServices    PurpleEventCallback + 34
12 ...   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
```

Comment: Code looks fine to me, maybe it is the wrong code its blaming

Comment: Show us the crash log or provide some other details. Thanks.

Comment: Is it posibble that delegate is released before alert is dismissed and dismiss message is sent to dangling pointer?

Comment: if there were a delegate that would be most common case however there is no delegate set!

Comment: try by setting the delegate:self